# Formik field placeholder does not disappear even if there is a value in the input react js

Tags: reactjs, formik, placeholder

since I can't yet embed images
I have a formik field and this field has a placeholder that place holder does not disappear it disappears only on focus on that field
what can I do ?

what I have tried  :

```
input:focus::-webkit-input-placeholder {
   color: transparent !important;
}
input:focus:-moz-placeholder {
   color: transparent !important;
} /* Firefox 18- */
input:focus::-moz-placeholder {
   color: transparent !important;
} /* Firefox 19+ */
input:focus:-ms-input-placeholder {
   color: transparent !important;
} /* oldIE ;) */
```